# MySQL Syntax Error in VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Here's the code of my button_click:

```
Private Sub Button10_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button10.Click
    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
    Dim dr As MySqlDataReader

    conn.ConnectionString = "server = localhost; user id = root; database = db; password = root"
    cmd.Connection = conn
    conn.Open()
    cmd.CommandText = " SELECT * FROM candidate WHERE idn = '" & TextBox4.Text & "'"
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

    If dr.HasRows Then
        MessageBox.Show("Entry I.D. No. already exist", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    ElseIf TextBox4.Text = "" Or TextBox5.Text = "" Or TextBox6.Text = "" Or TextBox7.Text = "" Or ComboBox1.Text = "" Or TextBox3.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please complete the required fields..", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    Else
        conn.Close()
        con.ConnectionString = "server = localhost; user id = root; database = db; password = root"
        cmd.Connection = con
        con.Open()
        Dim sqlQuery As String = "INSERT INTO candidate(idn,cfname,cmname,clname,cyr,sec,vyear,votes,pword) VALUES('" & TextBox4.Text & "','" & TextBox5.Text & "','" & TextBox6.Text & "','" & TextBox7.Text & "','" & ComboBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox3.Text & "',CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()),'-',(YEAR(NOW()) + 1),'0','" & TextBox2.Text & "')"
        Dim sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand

        With sqlCommand
            .CommandText = sqlQuery
            .Connection = con
            .ExecuteNonQuery()
        End With
        MsgBox("Record Inserted")
    End If
End Sub
```

what's wrong with my `INSERT` query? I can't seem to find anything wrong here, but VB.NET says it has error in `"` at line 1?

`"INSERT INTO candidate(vyear) VALUES(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()),'-',(YEAR(NOW()) + 1))"`

Comment: Hard to tell without the actual assignment/execution code.

Comment: I count 8 `(` and 7 `)` so you obviously missing a `)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a unbalanced open parenthesis before the second YEAR. Need to remove it

```
 "INSERT INTO candidate(vyear) VALUES( CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()),'-',YEAR(NOW()) + 1) )"
```

Looking at the updated code you really need to start to use parameterized queries

```
Using con = new MySqlConnection(......)
Using cmd = con.CreateCommand()
    con.Open()
    Dim sqlQuery As String = "INSERT INTO candidate " & _
        "(idn,cfname,cmname,clname,cyr,sec,vyear,votes,pword) VALUES(" & _ 
        "@idn, @cfname, @cmname, @clname, @cyr, @sec, " & _
        "CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()),'-',YEAR(NOW()) + 1), " & _
        "@votes, @pword"
    With cmd
        .CommandText = sqlQuery
        ' is idn an integer field, then pass it as integer.
        ' instead if it is an autoincrement then remove it and let the db calculate for you
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@idn", Convert.ToInt32(TextBox4.Text))
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@cfname, TextBox5.Text)

        .... and so on for every placeholder in the parameterized text above

        .ExecuteNonQuery()
    End With
    MsgBox("Record Inserted")
End Using
End Using
```

Comment: sir Steve just one thing, what should i put in `CreateCommand()` in this line `Using cmd = con.CreateCommand()`? just trying to learn parameterized query.

Comment: Nothing. No value is expected by that method. The connection creates  the command and automatically set itself in the command, the command text with other properties is set after in the with body. The call produces an instance of MySqlCommand with just the connection set then you add a parameter in the Parameters collection for each parameter placeholder "@xxxxx" present in the command text